# z-index and stacking order - make child lower than parent but higher than uncle

Tags: html, css, z-index, margin

Please see the code in [jsbin](https://jsbin.com/nedisipuse/edit?html,css,output)

Screenshot:

[image]

All I need is just to have blue on top, then white, then greens. So ideally:

[image]

I tried `z-index`, create stacking context... nothing worked.

It might have something to do with negative margin in CSS

I'm happy to change the HTML code or change the current CSS, as long as I can get the desired effect.

```css
.left,
.right {
  width: 200px;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: green;
  display: inline-block;
}
.bar {
  width: 20px;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: blue;
  display: inline-block;
}
.circle {
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-left: -10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="out">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="bar">
    <div class="circle"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

### Edit

I should have mentioned that my difficulty was mostly achieving the effect while keeping the current HTML setup (i.e. circle in bar). Turns out it doesn't seem possible, because

1. If no zindex on bar, can't make sure it's on top of circle
2. If set zindex on bar, then it creates new stacking context, then **circle** can't be on top of 2 greens. Because **greens** are on different stacking context

Comment: Why circle is inside bar? I see this as easy as one green div, one blue div and one circle, with z-index of green 1, blue 3 and circle 2.

Comment: edited my answer after reading more carefully :) sorry about that

Comment: Boyang so you want to keep your markup or as you already mentioned you are happy to change it?

Comment: @dippas I will mark it as a better answer, if you are able to keep the markup and achieve what's in the picture

Comment: you already have the answer with the same markup so stick with that

Comment: @dippas NO. None of the answers have circle **inside** bar as a child

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDITED : edited my answer after reading more carefully :) sorry about that

see here > [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Mihai_T/czn4o2cr/2/)

or snippet below :

```css
.left, .right {
  width: 200px;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: green;
  display: inline-block;
    position:relative;
       z-index:1;
}

.bar {
  width: 20px;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: blue;
  display: inline-block;
  z-index:6;
  position:relative;
 

}
.circle {
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  top: 10px;
  position:absolute;
 
 left:0;
 right:0;
  margin:0 auto;
  z-index:5;
}
.out {width:420px;position:relative;}
```

```html
<div class="out">
    <div class="left"></div><div class="bar"></div><div class="circle"></div><div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

**OR** if you don't want different bg color for `.left` and `.right` just use one big div `.out` and position the `bar` and `circle` on top of it :

```css
.out {
  position: relative;
  width: 420px;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: green;
}
.bar {
  width: 20px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
   position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right:0;
  margin:0 auto;
  z-index: 2
}
.circle {
   height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
   position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
   left: 0;
  right:0;
  margin:0 auto;
  z-index: 1
}
```

```html
<div class="out">
    <div class="bar"></div>
    <div class="circle"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, no this is not desired. Blue has to be on top of everything

Comment: @Boyang edited my answer after reading more carefully :) sorry about that

Comment: ahah so you edited the answer to look like mine? funny guy ;)

Comment: check my 2 solutions. 1 is 100% different than yours. ( first one ) , second yes, it looks like yours but it's not the same. in the same time i could say that u used the comment from the question to get your answer ( `Why circle is inside bar? I see this as easy as one green div, one blue div and one circle, with z-index of green 1, blue 3 and circle 2. – Marcos Pérez Gude 14 mins ago `) but i won't say that. i am a funny guy...but not right now

Comment: I don't even read comments in questions, they appears as "1 new comment"  or something like that, until I load it I don't see it, so yea I did it by myself, and I was just talking about your edited answer the one which is very similar to mine after you already had seen mine and had 1 downvote ;)

Comment: @Boyang this is funny you are marking an answer as accepted which was edited based on another ;)

Comment: as you don't read comments. i don't read other answers. they appear as "1 new answer"  . and i had 2 downvotes because my initial answer ( the first one )  was wrong because i read the question without paying enough attention. then...after i corrected my first answer...i thought of another solution, which i admit, it looks like yours but it's not EXACTLY the same. have a great day :)

Comment: @dippas you had also 6 min difference between your answer and the comment to the question. you don't read the comments, really ? . on a serious note. why would i read other answers if my answer was correct ( after i edited it ) and only AFTER i edited my answer and it was correct, i posted another solution that looks like yours. i will delete the second solution if that would make you happier

Comment: No, no, stay put. let it be

Comment: based on my knowledge in CSS and HTML ' lol ' . first...i was in a hurry ( i admit ) to post the first answer . i messed it up. then i was in a hurry to edit it because i was getting downvotes ( 2 already ) + comment from the OP . and after that it occurred to me that it was a solution too complicated  for a simple effect. so i thought of another, simpler solution.which , maybe because it's the most straight-forward solution to a simple, basic CSS HTML effect , looks like the solution provided by you.

Comment: but i repeat. if you want. i can delete the second solution. i don't want to get into discussions over a topic like this...

Answer (score 3):

you can simplify this using just the div `out` with `position` + `z-index`

```css
.out {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: green;
}
.bar {
  width: 20px;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: blue;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: 10
}
.circle {
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-left: -10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: 1
}
```

```html
<div class="out">
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="bar"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

What if we just interchange `.bar` as child element of `.circle`. And try as below,

```css
.left, .right {
  width: 200px;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: green;
  display: inline-block;
}
.bar {
  width: 20px;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: blue;
  margin:-10px 10px;
}
.circle {
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display:inline-block;
  position:absolute;
  margin:10px -20px;
}
```

```html
 <div class="out">
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="circle"><div class="bar"></div></div>
    <div class="right"></div>
 </div>
```

Comment: @Boyang will you please give some comment on this answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use transform.

https://jsbin.com/geconefine/1/edit?html,css,output

```
.out{
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
}

.left, .right {
  width: 200px;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: green;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  z-index: -2;
}

.bar {
  width: 20px;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: blue;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
.circle {
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-10px);
  margin-top: 10px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

Comment: blue needs to be on top

Answer (score 1):

You could even further simplify your markup and utilize a `pseudo selector` instead of wrestling with stacking order, and order elements naturally.

```css
.out {
  width: 400px;
  padding: 10px 0;
  background: green;
}
.circle {
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}
.circle:after {
  content: '';
  width: 20px;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: blue;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="out">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -3):

You need a position before z-index will do anything. Since I don't see any applied in your current css that might be your issue.

```
.left, .right{
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
.circle{
  position: relative;
  z-index: 4;
}
.bar{
  position: relative;
  z-index: 5;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to apply these to my jsbin? I tried and it doesn't work